# Notifications send using FBML do not work if app is not installed

Tags: facebook, notifications, fbml

I am having a big problem with FBML app generated notifications. The app sends two kind of notifications. One type of notification is to invite the user's friends to use the app (spreading the word), and second type is when user send request to his friends to check out his score on the app. The code for one of the invitation section is as follows. The other one is also similar to this with the exception of text.

```
<div style="width:580px;">   <fb:serverFbml width="582px" >
  <script type="text/fbml">
     <fb:request-form 
        method="post"           
        action="<?php echo $this->callback ?>/buddies/call"
       content="<?= htmlspecialchars('<fb:req-choice url="'.$this->application.'msg/invite_" label="Accept"/>Hi, I’m using My APP to find out about myslef, and that of my friends. Wanna join?”', ENT_QUOTES); ?>"
        type="event"
        target=""
        invite="true">
        <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="Invite your friends" exclude_ids="<?php echo $this->excludes;?>" email_invite="false" cols="3" max="35" />
    </fb:request-form>
</script>
```

Now the problem is that if the application is installed on the friends profile then the notification appears on the top globe and once clicked re-directs to the right page on the app. However, if the app is not installed then the notification appears on the top globe but when clicked nothing happens. I have checked via firebug that when clicked the page sends an AJAX call but nothing happens. Also the link that is generated is the same regardless of the fact that app is installed or not installed on the friends profile.

Any help will be most appreciated. I have deadline to meet and I am so short on time.

Thanks in advance.

Usman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the new Requests 2.0.  FBML is deprecated and will be completely removed from existence on June 1st (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/).

Here's the documentation on how to use the new Requests 2.0:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

as simple as (when specifying a specific friend):

```
function sendRequestToRecipients() {
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request',
    to: '499802820'
  }, requestCallback);
}
```

OR allow the user to choose which friends:

```
function sendRequestToRecipients() {
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request'
  }, requestCallback);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comments. Is it possible to pass a specific URL to which the user/friend is re-directed after accepting invitation? It was possible in FBML. I need to pass the id of the user who has sent the invitation as this information is used by my App. Any idea's, help, suggestion will be most appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can redirect the user to where ever you want using the new requests 2.0 dialog, just do so in your requestCallback function after you've saved the other important information. With the 2.0 dialog you can also get the user id sending the request as well as to whom he sent the requests to. Happy coding.

Comment: Hi DMCS, Thank you once again. An example of requestCallback will make my day :)

Comment: `function requestCallback(response) {//do something with the response per the documentation}`

Comment: Hi DMCS, sorry to be such a pain but I believe I am not explaining myself properly. If you have send me a notification, and once I click it I will be re-directed to a particular page on the app. From where I can set this "page". Also on that page how can the app figure out which user has send the notification. These two values are very critical for the app to function properly.

Comment: Hi DMCS, found the solution. Thank you for all the help